# PHP and SQLSTate error

Tags: php, sql

I have this PHP code:

```
<?php
require_once('../include/inner_global.php');
$id=$_REQUEST['id'];
$hostdb="localhost";
$namedb="architect";
$userdb="root";
$passdb="root";
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostdb; dbname=$namedb", $userdb, $passdb);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$conn->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
if(isset($_POST['submitDate'])){
if(!isset($_POST['Date'])){
    echo "No date selected";    
}else{
echo $d = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($_POST['Date']));
}


                    //foreach($result as $row){
    $sql1= "SELECT SUM(total_pay) AS total FROM workers WHERE date_of_pay = :d AND projects_id = :id";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql1);

    $stmt->bindValue(":d", $d);
    $stmt->bindValue(":projid", $id);
    $count = $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
    echo var_dump($result);
}
?>
```

And I am getting this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined' in C:\wamp\www\architect\pages\projDReport.php on line 25
```

does someone know what is going wrong? the global.php file, is for session detection, else it will take us to login page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `$stmt->bindValue(":projid", $id);` to    `$stmt->bindValue(":id", $id);`.

The values you are binding in prepared statements should have same names, as it defined in the statement. In that case it should be named `:id` and not `:projid`.